# How to call a vb.net function by name with by ref parameters

Tags: vb.net, invoke, dynamically-generated

We need to call a set of functions (currently around 30 or so) programatically by name. They all have the same signature so I've gone down the "invoke" route. I initially tried using delegates as I recalled doing that previously but that didn't achieve what I was after. So I've now looked at reflection to do it.

```
    Dim webapiType as type = type.gettype("fully.qualified.model.webapi", true, true)
dim webAPIConstructor as system.reflection.constructorinfo = webapitype.getconstructor(type.emptytypes)
dim webapiClassObject as object = webapiConstructor.invoke(new object(){})
dim webapiMethod as system.reflection.methodinfo = webapitype.getmethod("myFunctionName")
dim webapiValue as object = webapimethod.invoke(webapiclassobject, new object(){model, xmlREsponse, msg, exDAL})
```

That all works fine and calls my function "myFunctionName" but it doesn't set the xmlResponse object value, that stays as nothing. (the function I'm calling has byval model, byref xmlREsponse, byref msg and byref exDal)

If I call the method directly rather than invoking it then the xmlResponse parameter is returned.

So the issue is that the values of the byRef values aren't being returned.

Is there some other way of invoking the method so that the ByRef parameters are returned correctly or do I need to investigate some other concept ?

(I've looked at CalledName and the documentation says that it only passes "ByVal" so that's no use)

Comment: I know you said you already tried with delegates...but please tell us why that didn't work.  Why can't you use delegates?

Comment: I could create a delegate and pass the info (and the values came back) but I couldn't get it to define the delegate to point to the address of programatically.

dim delegateObject as delegateForWebAPICall = AddressOf c.myFunctionName I'd want to point the deletegate Object to the AddressOf "myFunctionName"

So that I can pass in the name as a string rather than it being hard-coded.

Comment: Why do you need to pass in the name as a string?  Where are these string names coming from?  You have a concrete number of methods, so why not just create a delegate when needed?

Comment: See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh(v=vs.110).aspx). It looks like, if the method signature accepts a particular parameter as by ref, then it is inferred as by ref when you call `Invoke()`

Comment: We're adding things into an existing architecture that we can't change.
However I have solved the issue.
Rather than adding the values "in-line" new object(){model, xmlREsponse, msg, exDAL}
I've created dim params as object() = new Object(){model, xmlREsponse, msg, exDAL}
And then pass that in as invoke(webapiClassObject, params)
Then the value is maintained but only in the params array, not the object added to the array. Which I guess makes sense.
The other option to pass in a delegate to the function instead I might investigate on an individual basis.

Comment: You need to give the object() array a name.  You'll need to reference it again after the Invoke() call to retrieve the updated reference in the 2nd element.

Comment: Forgive my inexperience, but does this help? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chsc1tx6(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Our solution has been to pass function delegates into a generic handler rather than the names. Works quite neatly. The only issue we ran into was the need to be able to pass some generic additional parameters so that's just gone in via a key value dictionary.